# How to toggle the content of an element by pressing a key?

Tags: javascript, html

Im currently trying to make a website where if i press q the p tag will change from "Q" to "A". This currently works with the code below. However the problem is that when pressing q it needs to go back to "A". I've tried making it work with removeEventListeners but it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
        if (event.key == "q") {
            document.getElementById("P1").innerText = "Q"
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: inside that handler change its content according to the currently shown character. So you just need to add an if condition that will set the value to A or Q based on its content

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I´m not sure i understand though.
This is what i have done and it doesn't work.

<script>
    document.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
        if (event.key == "q") {
            document.getElementById("P1").innerText = "Q"
        }
        if (event.key == "q") {
            document.getElementById("P1").innerText = "A"
        }
    });
</script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like [@diegod](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1221208/diegod) suggested in the comments you should check which character is currently shown in the `p` element and change the `innerText` accordingly:

```js
const p1 = document.getElementById("P1");

document.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
  if (event.key == "q") {
    if (p1.innerText == "A") {
      p1.innerText = "Q";
    } else {
      p1.innerText = "A";
    }
  }
});
```

Using [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) example:

```js
const p1 = document.getElementById("P1");

document.addEventListener("keypress", event => {
  if (event.key == "q") {
    p1.innerText = p1.innerText == "A" ? "Q" : "A";
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const $ = (prop) => document.querySelector(prop)

const changeToQ = () => {
  $('p').innerText = 'Q'
}

const reset = () => {
  $('p').innerText = 'A'
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'q') changeToQ()
})

document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'q') reset()
})
```

I think this is what are you looking for

Answer (score -1):

have your tried to make else statement

```
else{ document.getElementById("P1").innerText = "A"}
```

Comment: that's not what was asked... the key to press remains `q` and such else statement will act with any other key pressed instead of `q`