# Change text back and forth using a key

Tags: javascript, html

My assignment is to use events and navigate the DOM.

I have to create a script so that when i press Q while on my webpage, (>p<)A(>/p<) has to change to the letter Q, when i press Q again, the letter has to return to A.

Thanks, in advance! :-)

```js
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 81) {
    document.getElementById('A').innerText = "Q";
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="A">A</p>
```

Comment: We're not doing your homework.  We'll help you if you get stuck.

Comment: So first step bind an event listener to the document. Second select element, third change the text

Comment: I have been stuck for 2 hours but thank you for the comment james

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73852020/usage-of-event-listeners). Strange how two different users had exactly the same specific question. Classmates?

Comment: Avoid using `event.keyCode` if you write code for developers. Use `event.key`

Comment: As Roko already said, [`Event.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key) is the way to go now, as [`Event.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) has been deprecated.

Comment: This is another example of a hasty question closing. The question was clearly not about "how to use event listeners" but rather about "how to toggle a value". Admittedly, not a very new or original question, but the way it was treated was not very friendly towards a SO newbie.

Comment: @Carsten Massmann, I can see your point but even though the titles are worded differently both questions are about toggling the content of `p` element between "Q" and "A" by pressing the "q" key on the keyboard. The title of the original question is basically wrong as the question is actually not about the "Usage of event listeners" and it should be changed.

Answer (score 1):

Check, whether the current value already is "Q": `p.innerText=="Q"?"A":"Q"`

```js
const p=document.getElementById('A');
document.body.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (["q","Q"].includes(event.key)) {
    p.textContent = p.textContent=="Q"?"A":"Q";
  }
});
```

```html
<p id="A">A</p>
```

Comment: `innerText ` should be `textContent`

Comment: Yes, of course, `.textContent` is the "cleaner" solution ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of your letters and use the `%` Reminder Operator to loop over the index

```js
const letters = ["A", "Q"];  // Use as many as you like
const tot = letters.length;  // How many letters we have
let i = 0;                   // Start at letter index 0

const elA = document.querySelector('#A');

addEventListener("keydown", (evt) => {
  if (evt.key === "q") { // or use evt.code === "KeyQ" (if you don't care about Shift key)
    i += 1;    // increment
    i %= tot;  // loop
    elA.textContent = letters[i];
  }
});
```

```html
Click here to focus and use the keyboard letter "Q"
<h1 id="A">A</h1>
```